# Cannot install rdma-core

Tags: networking, drivers

when I try to install rdma-core I get this:

```
Setting up rdma-core (22.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Job for iwpmd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status iwpmd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript iwpmd, action "start" failed.
● iwpmd.service - iWarp Port Mapper
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iwpmd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-08-09 16:42:16 CEST; 5ms ago
     Docs: man:iwpmd
           file:/etc/iwpmd.conf
  Process: 13331 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iwpmd --systemd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13331 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

srp 09 16:42:16 ib102h systemd[1]: Starting iWarp Port Mapper...
srp 09 16:42:16 ib102h iwpmd[13331]: get_iwpm_param: Got param (name = nl_sock_rbuf_size val = 419430400)
srp 09 16:42:16 ib102h iwpmd[13331]: create_iwpm_socket_v6: Unable to create socket. Address family not supported by protocol.
srp 09 16:42:16 ib102h iwpmd[13331]: main: Couldn't start iWarp Port Mapper.
srp 09 16:42:16 ib102h systemd[1]: iwpmd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
srp 09 16:42:16 ib102h systemd[1]: iwpmd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
srp 09 16:42:16 ib102h systemd[1]: Failed to start iWarp Port Mapper.
dpkg: error processing package rdma-core (--configure):
 installed rdma-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

My IB device is:

```
Mellanox Technologies MT25408A0-FCC-QI ConnectX, Dual Port 40Gb/s InfiniBand / 10GigE Adapter IC with PCIe 2.0 x8 5.0GT/s Interface
```

When I do

```
lsmod | egrep 'mlx4|mthca|ib_ipoib|ib_umad'
```

it outputs this

```
ib_umad                24576  4
ib_ipoib              110592  0
ib_cm                  57344  2 rdma_cm,ib_ipoib
mlx4_ib               188416  0
ib_uverbs             114688  2 mlx4_ib,rdma_ucm
mlx4_en               118784  0
ib_core               249856  10 rdma_cm,ib_ipoib,rpcrdma,mlx4_ib,iw_cm,ib_iser,ib_umad,rdma_ucm,ib_uverbs,ib_cm
mlx4_core             294912  2 mlx4_ib,mlx4_en
devlink                65536  3 mlx4_core,mlx4_ib,mlx4_en
```

I did not find anything relevant on internet. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Update:

systemctl status iwpmd.service

```
● iwpmd.service - iWarp Port Mapper
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iwpmd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-08-11 22:26:40 CEST; 15s ago
     Docs: man:iwpmd
           file:/etc/iwpmd.conf
  Process: 23697 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iwpmd --systemd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 23697 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: Starting iWarp Port Mapper...
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h iwpmd[23697]: get_iwpm_param: Got param (name = nl_sock_rbuf_size val = 419430400)
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h iwpmd[23697]: create_iwpm_socket_v6: Unable to create socket. Address family not supported by protocol.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h iwpmd[23697]: main: Couldn't start iWarp Port Mapper.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: iwpmd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: iwpmd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: Failed to start iWarp Port Mapper.
```

journalctl -xe

```
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: Starting iWarp Port Mapper...
-- Subject: A start job for unit iwpmd.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit iwpmd.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 26948.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h iwpmd[23697]: get_iwpm_param: Got param (name = nl_sock_rbuf_size val = 419430400)
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h iwpmd[23697]: create_iwpm_socket_v6: Unable to create socket. Address family not supported by protocol.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h iwpmd[23697]: main: Couldn't start iWarp Port Mapper.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: iwpmd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit iwpmd.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: iwpmd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit iwpmd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
srp 11 22:26:40 ib102h systemd[1]: Failed to start iWarp Port Mapper.
-- Subject: A start job for unit iwpmd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit iwpmd.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 26948 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: Have you executed `systemctl status iwpmd.service` and `journalctl -xe` and see anything of value (E.G. did you configure the `iwpm` daemon?  Please [edit] your question to provide this relevant info.

Comment: I think it may be an issue only in 19.04 because I was working in 18.04.